Logout not clearing cookies properly in React application
I am working on a React application that uses cookies for authentication and Redux for state management. I have implemented a logout functionality, but I am facing an issue where the cookies are not being cleared properly upon logout. However, when I manually reset the application state, the cookies get cleared as expected.
Here's the relevant code for the logout functionality:
// useAuth.js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../store/slices/authSlice';

const useAuth = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { user, loading, error } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  // ... Other methods ...

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    const result = await Swal.fire({
      // ... Confirmation dialog code ...
    });

    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      authService.logout();
      dispatch(logout());

      await Swal.fire({
        // ... Success message code ...
      });

      navigate('/login', { replace: true });
    }
  };

  // ... Other methods ...
};

// auth.service.js
export const authService = {
  // ... Other methods ...

  logout: () => {
    Cookies.remove('token', { path: '/' });
    Cookies.remove('user', { path: '/' });
  },

  // ... Other methods ...
};

// AccountSidebar.js
import { useAuth } from '../../hooks/useAuth';

const AccountSidebar = ({ setActiveComponent, isOpen, setIsOpen }) => {
  const { logout } = useAuth();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    logout();
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  // ... Other code ...
};

// authSlice.js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    user: null,
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    // ... Other reducers ...
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { logout } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;

// store.js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from './slices/authSlice';
import userReducer from './slices/userSlice';
import paymentReducer from './slices/paymentSlice';
import flightReducer from './slices/flightSlice';
import flightSearchReducer from './slices/flightSearchSlice';
import flightFilterReducer from './slices/flightFilterSlice';
import registerReducer from './slices/registerSlice';
import resetPasswordReducer from './slices/resetPasswordSlice';

const dateSerializer = {
  serialize: (date) => (date instanceof Date ? date.toISOString() : date),
  deserialize: (dateString) => (dateString ? new Date(dateString) : null),
};

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    user: userReducer,
    payment: paymentReducer,
    flight: flightReducer,
    flightSearch: flightSearchReducer,
    flightFilter: flightFilterReducer,
    register: registerReducer,
    resetPassword: resetPasswordReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        // ... ignoredActions, ignoredActionPaths, ignoredPaths ...
      },
      serializeOptions: {
        serializer: {
          date: dateSerializer.serialize,
        },
        deserializer: {
          date: dateSerializer.deserialize,
        },
      },
    }),
});

export const serializeDate = (date) => {
  return date instanceof Date ? date.toISOString() : date;
};

export const deserializeDate = (dateString) => {
  return dateString ? new Date(dateString) : null;
};

export const resetStore = () => {
  store.dispatch({ type: 'auth/logout' });
  store.dispatch({ type: 'user/resetUserData' });
  store.dispatch({ type: 'flightSearch/resetFlightSearch' });
  store.dispatch({ type: 'flightFilter/clearAllFilters' });
  store.dispatch({ type: 'payment/resetPaymentState' });
  store.dispatch({ type: 'register/resetRegisterState' });
  store.dispatch({ type: 'resetPassword/resetState' });
};

The problem is that after calling authService.logout() and dispatching the logout action from the AccountSidebar component, the cookies (token and user) are not being cleared immediately. They persist in the browser until I manually reset the application state and refresh web.
I have tried the following:
Setting the path option to '/' while removing the cookies using Cookies.remove('token', { path: '/' }) and Cookies.remove('user', { path: '/' }) in the authService.logout() method. I expected this to ensure that the cookies are cleared for the entire application.
Dispatching the logout action from the Redux slice after calling authService.logout() to update the Redux state accordingly. I expected this to clear the user data from the Redux store.
Navigating to the login page using navigate('/login', { replace: true }) after dispatching the logout action. I expected this to redirect the user to the login page and replace the current history entry.
However, despite trying these steps, the cookies (token and user) are not being cleared immediately upon logout. They persist in the browser until I manually refresh the page or call the resetStore() function to reset the entire Redux store.
On the other hand, when I manually refresh the page or call resetStore(), the cookies get cleared as expected, and the user is redirected to the login page.
I expected that calling authService.logout(), dispatching the logout action, and navigating to the login page would be sufficient to clear the cookies and log the user out properly. However, it seems that there is some issue preventing the cookies from being cleared immediately.
I have double-checked that I am not using any additional libraries like Redux Persist to persist the Redux state. I am solely relying on cookies for authentication.

Things seem a little over-complicated. Why not make your logout action an asynchronous action and handle all the logout logic there, including clearing cookies, instead of spreading it across a synchronous action, a service module, a custom hook, and local callback in the UI component? You can use the generated fulfilled, pending, and rejected actions to handle any loading states and UI. What cookie library are you using? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] and exact reproduction steps.
